# Prestashop 1.7 custom CMS page CSS best practice

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I have created a custom page in prestashop 1.7 by creating a new controller.
I saw that there is a way to create CMS pages in the backend. How can I create a template for this CMS page that contains the custom CSS and JS for this specific page?

Answer (score 0):

In a page cms, you can identify it in css and JS thanks to its ID "cms" and then thanks to its class uniquer: cms-id-x

See the body tag of a CMS page:

```
<body id="cms" class="lang-fr country-us currency-usd layout-full-width page-cms tax-display-disabled cms-id-1">
```

Regards

Comment: but how can I use my custom CSS and JS in this cms page?

Comment: In your file css : #cms .cms-id-1 { INSTRUCTION }


In your JS file :
if ($('#cms .cms-id-1').length){
 INSTRUCTION
}

Comment: Where do I find the CSS and JS file?

Comment: IN your theme custom.css and global.js